# How to find which rule is firing in Endeca PageBuilder?

Tags: workbench, endeca, experience-manager

Endeca's PageBuilder shows a particular landing page depending on which section of the site you're viewing.  In our installation, a retail site, there are a ton of landing pages, so troubleshooting can be tough.  Consider this situation:

I've created a template that should launch at location "Section: Men's wear", "Category: Ties".  Instead, a different landing page is shown.  It turns out someone had inserted a rule at a higher priority that applied to anything under "Section: Men's wear".  Is there a way of querying the rule manager to find out which rule will fire for a particular set of dimensions, letting me go straight to that rule to edit it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use page builder or the rule manager and preview any url state. Just click the preview button that is located on the landing page view or rule manager view.

Also check out:
https://endecacommunity.com/

Answer (score 1):

User @Wiszh has answered this in detail here:
[Determine Rules triggered by endeca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540636/determine-rules-triggered-by-endeca?rq=1)

---

The proper way to do this is with the Content Assembler API (endeca_content.jar). You need to create a content query and retrive the content object:

```
ContentItem content = results.getContent();
content.getName();
```